# how to make a pop up Window which can be closed by clicking only

Tags: javascript

I have a website which is based on technology products reviews. I have many unique visitors every day. I use a company to earn some money. They give advertisement in my website and when my visitors click them i got some revenue which I used to pay my domain bill.

Now I want every visitor will click my ads. So I want a pop up Window. When any visitor will enter in my site he will be showed an pop up Window where i place my ad and he can only enter if he click that ads. It's like looking system.

So can it be done?

Comment: That's a really great way to stop you from having return visitors. No-one wants to be forced to click ads to enter your site, and people will quickly learn that and stop coming back.

Comment: This may well be against the terms and conditions of the ad provider anyway. Presumably they want clicks from people genuinely interested.

Answer (score 0):

You can display a div which covers your website. This div contains your ad. You can define a close-image to hide the div or also you can react with the onClick-Event in the div.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a modal div at body onload or with jQuery at document.ready

then If the visitor click close the div and they can visit your page, in another case, if click close you redirect to another page (document.location), for example, explaining why they have to click on the ads

Answer (score 0):

You can make a cookie:`isClicked`, value `false`
If the user click on your ad(`popup`), you set this on `true`.
Now you control with your `main page`: is the cookie `true`?
If yes, you allow the user to load the page.